# PHP include() function

Tags: php

In my web application there are 4 pages (About.html, Register.html,Quiz.html,Topic.html ) in each page navigation, header and footer sections are same. Now I want to put all these sections into single php include() functions(not multiple php files )

Comment: What is your question?  Where exactly are you having issues?

Comment: why are people downvoting this? this is legitimate fundamental question for beginners. if you downvote, perhaps you can leave a comment about where to go to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Then you may create a file perhaps named `template.php` which contains:

```
function printHeader($arg=null) {
    echo "<div class='header'>Here is your header contents!</div>";
}
function printFooter($arg=null) {
    echo "<div class='footer'>Here is your footer contents!</div>";
}
```

and just call them appropriately in each page having the same template, for example in the "about" page:

```
include_once "template.php";
// ...
printHeader();
// ...
printFooter();
// ...
```

Comment: well, he is using HTML files, so he needs a "hub file" to include the HTML files into

Answer (score 1):

let's consider an index.php file

in that file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo !empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : 'Home'; ?></title>
<!-- head info -->
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
<?php foreach( array( 'About', 'Register', 'Quiz', 'Topic' ) as $page ) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?page=<?php echo $page; ?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<div id="content">
<?php if ( !empty( $_GET['page'] ) ) : ?>
<h2><?php echo $_GET['page']; ?></h2>
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . $_GET['page'] . '.html' );
    echo reset( explode( '</body>', end( explode( '<body>', $content ) ) ) );
else : ?>
*** home page (default) content goes here (or include it from a separate file too) ***
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<hr />
This is the footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

you must understand that given the broad scope of your question, and the fact you are using HTML files, this solution is incredibly basic. but it answers your question and/or plants the seed for learning from here.

for example, using `is_file()` to check that the page actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

1) About.html, Register.html,Quiz.html,Topic.html rename them to .php.

2) add 'sections.php'

```
function addHeader(){
    echo "THIS IS HEADER!!!";
}
function addFooter(){
    echo "THIS IS FOOTER!!!";
}
function addSparta(){
    echo "THIS IS SPARTA!!!";
}
```

3) in Topic.php(and other files) add

```
include_once 'sections.php';
```

4) use those functions to print out what you need.

But still its not very good way to compose your pages.